# vuejs v-validate custom validation rule: max value must bigger than min value that user input

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vee-validate

Below are my code for 2 input fields in vuejs. The current validation rule is they both need to be numeric. I've read the [official document here](https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/guide/custom-rules.html).

I need to add another rule, that `max-amount` must be bigger than `min-amount`. The trick is min-amount is user input, not pre-determined. How should I implement this customize validator?

```
        <div class="min-section">
          <label>Min</label>
          <input type="text" 
          class="uk-input"
          name="min-amount"
          v-validate="'numeric'"
          v-model="minAmount" />
        </div>
        <div class="max-section">
          <label>Max</label>
          <input type="text" 
          class="uk-input"
          name="max-amount" 
          v-validate="'numeric'"
          v-model="maxAmount"/>
        </div>
```

Comment: The [target dependent rules](https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/guide/custom-rules.html#target-dependant-rules) section in the documentation covers this.

Answer (score 7):

You could bind [`min_value`](https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/guide/rules.html#min-value) in the `v-validate` rules of the max-amount `<input>`:

```html
<input name="min-amount" v-model="minAmount">
<input name="max-amount"
       v-validate="'numeric|min_value:' + minAmount"
       v-model="maxAmount">
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/4859z2mmq0)

Also note if you don't have a specific reason to use a text input, you should consider using [`<input type="number">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number) (instead of `<input type="text">`) so that the user could only enter numeric values.